# Latex Table Does Not Appear Where I Put It Although There Is Enough Space

Tags: tables, threeparttable, sidewaystable

I have the following problem: I want to insert a table in the appendix of my paper. I used the command /newpage to start the section of the appendix in which I want the table to appear on a new page. The table is not that big, but Latex somehow shifts it to a new page so that it does not appear where I want it to appear. I would kindly ask for some help so that the table appears directly after the  header of the subsection and not on the next page.

This is some basic code for my document:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage]{article} % give the document type
\input{01_layout} %the command 'include' loads the corresponding file, alternatively, this file can be inserted here.

% ========================================================================================================

%List of graphics;

\graphicspath{{graphics/}} % this is the path for graphics (insert your graphics in this folder)
\makeindex
% ========================================================================================================
\begin{document} % start of the document
.
.
.
.
\newpage
\include{appendix} % include the appendix file
\newpage
```

And the appendix file looks as follows:

```
% Appendix
\newpage
\begin{appendix}
\section{Appendix}
.
.
.
.

\newpage
\subsection{Empirical Results}
\label{emp_res_app}
\subsubsection{In-Sample Correlations}
\label{samp_corr_app}
\input{tables/corr_table}
\end{appendix}
\newpage
```

Finally, this is the code for my table:

````
\begin{sidewaystable}[!htbp] 
\centering 
\begin{threeparttable} 
\caption{Cross-Sectional Correlations} \label{corr_table} 
\setlength\tabcolsep{1.5pt} 
\begin{tabular}{lccccccccccc} 
\toprule \toprule 
{} & $Earn$ & $d^{+}$ & $d^{-}$ & $BkEq$ & $TACC$ & $OCF$ & $SPI$ & $LEV$ & $PAYOUT$ & $PAYER$   \\ \midrule $Earn$ & 1.0*** & 0.55*** & -0.55*** & 0.61*** & -0.08*** & 0.72*** & -0.1*** & 0.04*** & 0.47*** & 0.38*** \\
 $d^{+}$ & 0.55*** & 1.0*** & -1.0*** & 0.33*** & 0.01* & 0.37*** & -0.02*** & 0.02*** & 0.25*** & 0.35*** \\
 $d^{-}$ & -0.55*** & -1.0*** & 1.0*** & -0.33*** & -0.01* & -0.37*** & 0.02*** & -0.02*** & -0.25*** & -0.35*** \\
 $BkEq$ & 0.61*** & 0.33*** & -0.33*** & 1.0*** & -0.38*** & 0.67*** & -0.1*** & 0.03*** & 0.44*** & 0.39*** \\
 $TACC$ & -0.08*** & 0.01* & -0.01* & -0.38*** & 1.0*** & -0.72*** & 0.06*** & -0.09*** & -0.25*** & -0.18*** \\
 $OCF$ & 0.72*** & 0.37*** & -0.37*** & 0.67*** & -0.72*** & 1.0*** & -0.11*** & 0.09*** & 0.49*** & 0.39*** \\
 $SPI$ & -0.1*** & -0.02*** & 0.02*** & -0.1*** & 0.06*** & -0.11*** & 1.0*** & -0.05*** & -0.06*** & -0.04*** \\
 $LEV$ & 0.04*** & 0.02*** & -0.02*** & 0.03*** & -0.09*** & 0.09*** & -0.05*** & 1.0*** & 0.07*** & 0.06*** \\
 $PAYOUT$ & 0.47*** & 0.25*** & -0.25*** & 0.44*** & -0.25*** & 0.49*** & -0.06*** & 0.07*** & 1.0*** & 0.64*** \\
 $PAYER$ & 0.38*** & 0.35*** & -0.35*** & 0.39*** & -0.18*** & 0.39*** & -0.04*** & 0.06*** & 0.64*** & 1.0*** \\
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular} 
\begin{tablenotes} \small \item \textbf{Table \ref{corr_table}} displays Pearson correlations for the entire sample, i.e. the pooled cross-section of firms from 1988 to 2021 including all variables of the forecast models for the conditional first and second moment of future earnings. However, in order to conserve space, all interacted variables as well as the industry dummies are omitted in this table.\end{tablenotes} 
\end{threeparttable} 
\end{sidewaystable}```
````

Comment: `sidewaystable` is a float which is positioned by LaTeX either at the top or the bottom of a page or on a new page. If you don't like this behaviour, don't use a float.

Answer (score 1):

The environment `sidewaystable` is a floating environment. Such floats are typically positioned automatically by LaTeX at the top or at the bottom of a page. If neither fits, they are placed on a new page.

You use a `threepartstable` which already nicely handles things such as captions which may lead to some problems if not placed inside a float. In short, if you don't want things to behave like a float, do not place them inside a floating environment.

Therefore, I'd suggest that you just place your table in a box that is rotated by 90 degrees:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage]{article} 
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry} % with the default margins, the table would not fit
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{appendix}
\section{Appendix}
\subsection{Empirical Results}
\label{emp_res_app}
\subsubsection{In-Sample Correlations}
\label{samp_corr_app}
{\centering\rotatebox{90}{%
\begin{threeparttable} 
\caption{Cross-Sectional Correlations} \label{corr_table} 
\setlength\tabcolsep{1.5pt} 
\begin{tabular}{lccccccccccc} 
\toprule \toprule 
{} & $Earn$ & $d^{+}$ & $d^{-}$ & $BkEq$ & $TACC$ & $OCF$ & $SPI$ & $LEV$ & $PAYOUT$ & $PAYER$   \\ \midrule $Earn$ & 1.0*** & 0.55*** & -0.55*** & 0.61*** & -0.08*** & 0.72*** & -0.1*** & 0.04*** & 0.47*** & 0.38*** \\
 $d^{+}$ & 0.55*** & 1.0*** & -1.0*** & 0.33*** & 0.01* & 0.37*** & -0.02*** & 0.02*** & 0.25*** & 0.35*** \\
 $d^{-}$ & -0.55*** & -1.0*** & 1.0*** & -0.33*** & -0.01* & -0.37*** & 0.02*** & -0.02*** & -0.25*** & -0.35*** \\
 $BkEq$ & 0.61*** & 0.33*** & -0.33*** & 1.0*** & -0.38*** & 0.67*** & -0.1*** & 0.03*** & 0.44*** & 0.39*** \\
 $TACC$ & -0.08*** & 0.01* & -0.01* & -0.38*** & 1.0*** & -0.72*** & 0.06*** & -0.09*** & -0.25*** & -0.18*** \\
 $OCF$ & 0.72*** & 0.37*** & -0.37*** & 0.67*** & -0.72*** & 1.0*** & -0.11*** & 0.09*** & 0.49*** & 0.39*** \\
 $SPI$ & -0.1*** & -0.02*** & 0.02*** & -0.1*** & 0.06*** & -0.11*** & 1.0*** & -0.05*** & -0.06*** & -0.04*** \\
 $LEV$ & 0.04*** & 0.02*** & -0.02*** & 0.03*** & -0.09*** & 0.09*** & -0.05*** & 1.0*** & 0.07*** & 0.06*** \\
 $PAYOUT$ & 0.47*** & 0.25*** & -0.25*** & 0.44*** & -0.25*** & 0.49*** & -0.06*** & 0.07*** & 1.0*** & 0.64*** \\
 $PAYER$ & 0.38*** & 0.35*** & -0.35*** & 0.39*** & -0.18*** & 0.39*** & -0.04*** & 0.06*** & 0.64*** & 1.0*** \\
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular} 
\begin{tablenotes} \small \item \textbf{Table \ref{corr_table}} displays Pearson correlations for the entire sample, i.e. the pooled cross-section of firms from 1988 to 2021 including all variables of the forecast models for the conditional first and second moment of future earnings. However, in order to conserve space, all interacted variables as well as the industry dummies are omitted in this table.\end{tablenotes} 
\end{threeparttable} 
}\par}

Bla bla
\end{appendix}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(In the likely case that you load the `graphicx` package, you don't need to load the `rotating` package for the above to work. I just assumed that you load the `rotating` package, since this packages provides the `sidewaystable` environment, so I kept it in the code.)

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked beautifully!